# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error after multiple attempts

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I've tried a thousand and one ways to do this code and assign a specific time to each array address but it always gives me an index error. I can't tell my mistake, please help.. Thanks

FYI we are using a provided input class so don't mind the ITI1120.readDouble() lines

```
System.out.println("Enter a maximum time: ");
double max = ITI1120.readDouble();
System.out.println("Enter a time step: ");
double h = ITI1120.readDouble();
double [] t = new double[] {};
int k = 0;
t[k] = 0.0;
while (t[k]<=max)
{
  k = k + 1;
  t[k] = t[k-1] + h;
  System.out.println(t[k]);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `double [] t = new double[] {};` to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried a thousand and one ways to do this code

A thousand?  Learn how to use a debugger.  It'll be obvious.

You have a max time and a time step.  I'd calculate the number of array elements I needed to store all those times:

```
int n = (int)max/h + 1;
```

Then declare the array with that length.

```
System.out.println("Enter a maximum time: ");
double max = ITI1120.readDouble();
System.out.println("Enter a time step: ");
double h = ITI1120.readDouble();
// This is an array of length zero.
int n = (int)max/h + 1;
double [] t = new double[n];
int k = 0;
t[k] = 0.0;
while (t[k]<=max)
{
  k = k + 1;
  // There's no t[1] in a zero length array.
  t[k] = t[k-1] + h;
  System.out.println(t[k]);
}
```

Comment: thank you it finally works! such an obvious mistake that just flew over my head

Answer (score 0):

You should specify size of your array `t` because you try to access element `t[0]` which does not exist.

Comment: Yes zero, that's why element `t[0]` does not exist.

Comment: the thing is the length is only determined by the division of max and h, both doubles.

Comment: So you can calculate maximum size of array before.

Answer (score 0):

First specify the size of your array t.

second:
Lets say the index of your array is 10 and k is currently 10.
In your while loop you add +1 to k, k is now 11.
Next:

```
t[k] = t[k-1] + h;
```

This means:

```
t[11] = t[11-1] + h;
```

Since your index is 10, this will alsogive an outOfBoundException